# Can not find the circuit breaker without power

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker

I have an outdoor outlet that when I came home, the cover was open.  The outlet is dead.  The GFCI is in the master bathroom and another is in the other bathroom and both are dead.  When I push the master bathroom reset, it goes on and immediately goes off.  I purchased a circuit breaker finder but it doesn't work if there is no power to the outlet.  All circuit breakers were turned off and back on and I have no idea how to find the correct breaker to shut it off to remove and replace the outside outlet.  Any advice?

Comment: Does the GFCI in the master bathroom have power?

Comment: You find that out by pushing reset. If it instantly Trips Again, it has power. If it doesn't even reset, it does not have power. If it resets but test doesn't work, then it doesn't have power.

Comment: So you have 1 GFCI feeding a second GFCI ? It sounds like this could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If your GFCI is trying to reset then you do have power at the source conductor attached to you GFCI.

You need to remove the cover of the GFCI and carefully unscrew and pull out the receptacle. Use a non contact tester to see if there is power at the GFCI. If it does then get a helper and have them test the receptacle while you go through panel turn each breaker on then off until you find the one that turns the power off at the receptacle.